# What does rawobject "object no" command mean in PeePDF?

Tags: python, pdf

My PDF is password protected. I started analysing it using PeePDF. In its console, I tried this command

```
PPDF> rawobject 4

<< /O <0ba3835f88f90388e74e54584125ce142be0de24c6b0d37746e075b891756671>
/Filter /Standard
/Length 128
/V 2
/U <c4a65b450077d25919a3fd30e4460eff00000000000000000000000000000000>
/R 3
/P -1 >>
```

and when I tried this command ,

```
PPDF> info 4

Offset: 285
Size: 206
MD5: a788b5a9e44449e32679ec84ca100134
Object: dictionary
References: []
```

Object 4 contains encryption dictionary. So , at /O is owner password, /U is user password. What are those hashes at each /O and /U ? Are those hashes of owner and user passwords ? What does info 4 discloses using MD5 record there ?

Please help me.

Comment: *"What are those hashes at each /O and /U ?"* - that is explained in the pdf specification. Do you have specific questions in regard to the specification?

Comment: Are those  hashes of exact passwords we enter or are they appended with some additional string before encrypting PDF ?

Comment: See ISO 32000-1 section 7.6.3.4 "Password Algorithms" and new algorithms in ISO 32000-2.